# Flutter : Difference between InkWell and InkResponse?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am Relatively new to Flutter Development, and while i was learning i came across the Ink Widgets that responds to touches while also showing some animation splash effect.

*But, there are two almost similar type of widgets that is InkWell and InkResponse.*

I could not find proper difference between those two from its class properties.

So, Can somebody explain what is the Main Difference between those two and, in which scenario i can use them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the 2 main differences between them are :

1. they both make a splash but `InkWell` is for rectangular shapes only while `InkResponse` can be clipped.
2. when the splash starts in `InkWell` but `InkResponse` will move the splash center to the `child` center .

last but not least and that's some thing am not sure of that the `InkResponse` deliver a `Material` widget with it's `child` but `InkWell` doesn't .

Comment: `"they both make a splash but InkWell is for rectangular shapes only while InkResponse can be clipped."` - see [InkWell.customBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkResponse/customBorder.html) - it can be passed directly in [InkWell constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell/InkWell.html)

Answer (score 3):

InkResponse does two things when responding to a tap:

1, It starts to animate a highlight -> Default is Circle in center.

2, It starts to animate a splash.

[InkResponse](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/material/ink_response_large.png)

InlWell is a InkResponse with the highlight is a rectangle the size of the box.

[InlWell](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/material/ink_well.png)

Answer (score 1):

Both InkWell and InkResponse are widgets provided by Flutter for handling touch interactions and displaying splash effects. They are quite similar in functionality, but there are some differences between them in terms of usage and behavior.

**1. InkWell:**

```
Primary Use: InkWell is primarily used to wrap its child widget and provide a material ripple effect in response to touch interactions.

Properties:

   onTap: A callback function that is called when the InkWell is tapped.

   onDoubleTap: A callback function that is called when the InkWell is double-tapped.

   onLongPress: A callback function that is called when a long press is detected on the InkWell.

   child: The widget that is wrapped by InkWell.


Behavior:
   InkWell is more suited for cases where you need to handle common touch interactions such as tapping, double-tapping, and long-pressing.
```

**2. InkResponse:**

```
Primary Use: InkResponse is used to provide a visual response to touches while also handling touch events.

Properties:

   onTap: A callback function that is called when the InkResponse is tapped.

   onLongPress: A callback function that is called when a long press is detected on the InkResponse.

   onHighlightChanged: A callback function that is called when the highlight state of the InkResponse changes.

   child: The widget that is wrapped by InkResponse.

   highlightShape: The shape of the highlight that appears during touch interactions.

Behavior:

   InkResponse is more flexible and allows you to customize the visual feedback (highlight shape) during touch interactions.

   It's suitable when you need to customize the highlight shape or handle highlight state changes.
```

**When to Use Each:**

**Use InkWell When:**

```
You need a simple material ripple effect in response to touch interactions.

You want to handle common touch events like tapping, double-tapping, and long-pressing.
```

**Use InkResponse When:**

```
You need more control over the visual feedback during touch interactions.

You want to customize the shape of the highlight or handle highlight state changes.
```

In summary, InkWell is simpler and more straightforward for basic touch interactions with a material ripple effect, while InkResponse provides more customization options for touch feedback and is suitable for more complex touch interaction scenarios. Choose the one that best fits your specific use case and requirements.